# How to set a counter and increment 1 every 3 second and display it in label

Tags: c#

```
 private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what exactly your goal is, but maybe you can play around with the Stopwatch class from System.Diagnostics

Comment: One would assume that you set the timer interval to 3 seconds (3000ms), implement a field in the class to track the value, increment it within the event handler and update the label with the new value.

Comment: how i can to set the timer interval?

Comment: It's a property of the timer. If you added the timer by dragging it onto your form you can access it by clicking on the timer, and then you'll see it in the properties window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code to do that. Just add a Label named "label1" on your window.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Timer timer3;
    private int counter;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter = 0;

        timer3 = new Timer();
        timer3.Interval = 3000;
        timer3.Tick += Timer3_Tick;
        timer3.Start();
    }

    private void Timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        label1.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or even `label1.Text = (int.TryParse(label1.Text, out int v) ? v + 1 : 0).ToString();` in order to get rid of `counter`

Comment: thanks too much but can i use this way in class and calling the function in timer_click ?

Comment: timer_click ? If you mean starting the timer in a button_Click event instead of Form_Load, yes you can. But i'm not sure to understand the question.